# Using {.tabset} with bookdown::bs4_book()

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown

I'm creating a {[bookdown](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/)} project using the new [`bookdown::bs4_book()`](https://pkgs.rstudio.com/bookdown/reference/bs4_book.html) output. However, when I try to add tabs to a chapter using `{.tabset}` as described [here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/html-tabs.html), the tabs are not generated. Instead, the document is rendered in the normal linear layout.

Is it possible to use `{.tabset}` with `bookdown::bs4_book()`?

I've made a minimal `bs4_book()` project in [this GitHub repo](https://github.com/wjakethompson/bs4-reprex), and the rendered output is hosted here: https://bs4-reprex.netlify.app/intro.html

Here is the raw R Markdown code for the linked chapter (also available in the repo [here](https://github.com/wjakethompson/bs4-reprex/blob/main/01-intro.Rmd)).

````
# Introduction {#intro}

You can label chapter and section titles using `{#label}` after them, e.g., we can reference Chapter \@ref(intro).
If you do not manually label them, there will be automatic labels anyway, e.g., Chapter \@ref(methods).

## Figures and Tables {.tabset}

### Figures

Figures and tables with captions will be placed in `figure` and `table` environments, respectively.

```{r nice-fig, fig.cap='Here is a nice figure!', out.width='80%', fig.asp=.75, fig.align='center'}
par(mar = c(4, 4, .1, .1))
plot(pressure, type = 'b', pch = 19)
```

### Tables

Reference a figure by its code chunk label with the `fig:` prefix, e.g., see Figure \@ref(fig:nice-fig).
Similarly, you can reference tables generated from `knitr::kable()`, e.g., see Table \@ref(tab:nice-tab).

```{r nice-tab, tidy=FALSE}
knitr::kable(
  head(iris, 20), caption = 'Here is a nice table!',
  booktabs = TRUE
)
```

##  {.unnumbered}

You can write citations, too.
For example, we are using the **bookdown** package [@R-bookdown] in this sample book, which was built on top of R Markdown and **knitr** [@xie2015].
````

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [this response](https://community.rstudio.com/t/using-tabset-with-bookdown-bs4-book/94218/2), `.tabset` is not a supported feature of {bookdown}. However, this can still be achieved using `xaringanExtra::use_panelset()`.

````
```{r panel-setup, include = FALSE}
xaringanExtra::use_panelset()
xaringanExtra::style_panelset(font_family = "inherit")
```

# Introduction {#intro}

You can label chapter and section titles using `{#label}` after them, e.g., we can reference Chapter \@ref(intro).
If you do not manually label them, there will be automatic labels anyway, e.g., Chapter \@ref(methods).

## Figures and Tables {.panelset}

### Figures

Figures and tables with captions will be placed in `figure` and `table` environments, respectively.

```{r nice-fig, fig.cap='Here is a nice figure!', out.width='80%', fig.asp=.75, fig.align='center'}
par(mar = c(4, 4, .1, .1))
plot(pressure, type = 'b', pch = 19)
```

### Tables

Reference a figure by its code chunk label with the `fig:` prefix, e.g., see Figure \@ref(fig:nice-fig).
Similarly, you can reference tables generated from `knitr::kable()`, e.g., see Table \@ref(tab:nice-tab).

```{r nice-tab, tidy=FALSE}
knitr::kable(
  head(iris, 20), caption = 'Here is a nice table!',
  booktabs = TRUE
)
```

##  {.unnumbered}

You can write citations, too.
For example, we are using the **bookdown** package [@R-bookdown] in this sample book, which was built on top of R Markdown and **knitr** [@xie2015].
````

{xaringanExtra} isn't on CRAN yet, but can be installed from GitHub with `remotes::install_github("gadenbuie/xaringanExtra")`. Also note that pansel sets are not portable to non-HTML bookdown outputs (e.g., PDF), which is why tabset is not natively supported in bookdown.

Comment: `style_panelset_tabs` has now replaced `style_panelset`

Comment: Can this be done in `bookdown` format `gitbook`?